# Highlighting with criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I can't seem to figure this one out through google.

I'm trying to highlight a cell that is not equal to 8% except for the heading.

Using this code:

```
Private Sub Highlight()
 Dim percentage As Range
 Set percentage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Range("H2:H10")

 For Each cell In percentage
  If percentage <> "8%" Then
   cell.Interior.Color = 255
  End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Would be grateful for any help!

Comment: `If cell.Value <> 0.08 Then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `dim cell as range` first and the following is you want:

Only when data is entered it will highlight the cell

```
Private Sub Highlight()
 Dim percentage As Range
 Dim cell As Range
 Set percentage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Range("H2:H10")

 For Each cell In percentage
  If cell.Value <> 0.08 And cell.Value <> "" Then
     cell.Interior.Color = 255
  End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
Private Sub Highlight()
 Dim percentage As Range
 Set percentage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MasterSheet").Range("H2:H10")

 For Each cell In percentage
 If cell <> 0.08 Then
   cell.Interior.Color = 255
 End If
 Next
End Sub
```

You can do similar things using the [Conditional Formatting in Excel](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/10/18/change-background-color-excel-based-on-cell-value/)
[image]

When you use this feature, even blank cells also would get formatted, to avoid this create another rule that will not do any formatting for those cells

Click the New Rule button in the rules manager and from the list of conditions, select ‘Format only cells that contain’ and select ‘Blank’ under the ‘Format only cells with’ dropdown. Click OK.

Comment: Thanks! How could I set it so only when data is entered it will highlight the cell

Comment: It's possible based on event, However I would recommend you to use cell conditional formatting instead on VBA code. Refer this https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/10/18/change-background-color-excel-based-on-cell-value/